# Formula to return value from a range will not work in a DAX measure, but works in a DAX Column

Tags: excel, dax, powerbi-desktop

This is driving me nuts.   I have never encountered this before.

I have a table (Excel Based called 'Metric Ranges'  That contains a series of Metrics and their scoring range values (Lower Limit and Upper Limit).

[Metric Values Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7qcm.png)

I need to create a measure that will pass in the the Metric's ID, and Value into this table and return the score based on the ranges.  The formula below works fine in a table column and returns the Score, but for some reason as a Measure, it will not return the value.  When I test and return all the VAR's I get values returned, so I know it's not the values there, it is the actual Calculation and that is not working.  The Score returned is a blank value.

```
Net Savings Year to date =
VAR MetricValue = [Savings % Annualize Goal]
VAR MetricPrgm = "4003"
VAR MetricId = 1
VAR Score =
    CALCULATE(
        VALUES( 'Metric Ranges'[Score] ),
        FILTER(
            'Metric Ranges',
            'Metric Ranges'[MetricId] = MetricId
                && 'Metric Ranges'[Program] = MetricPrgm
                && MetricValue > 'Metric Ranges'[Lower Range]
                && MetricValue <= 'Metric Ranges'[Upper Range]
        )
    )
RETURN
    MetricId
```

Answer (score 0):

When a calculated column is evaluated, a row context exist and to have the corresponding filter context a CALCULATE is required, to trigger a context transition.

When a measure is evaluated instead, there is the filter context but no row context.

This means that when evaluating the `FILTER( 'Metric Ranges' ...)` in the measure, only the `Metric Ranges` portion in the filter context is used. Instead, in the calculated column the whole table is used. To make this code work we must change it to work with a filter context. This might be a possible solution

```
Net Savings Year to date =
VAR MetricValue = [Savings % Annualize Goal]
VAR MetricPrgm = "4003"
VAR MetricId = 1
VAR Score =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( 'Metric Ranges'[Score] ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'Metric Ranges' ),
            'Metric Ranges'[MetricId] = MetricId
                && 'Metric Ranges'[Program] = MetricPrgm
                && MetricValue > 'Metric Ranges'[Lower Range]
                && MetricValue <= 'Metric Ranges'[Upper Range]
        )
    )
RETURN
    MetricId
```